# express.js https app over forwarded ssh remote port

Tags: express, curl, ssh, https, portforwarding

I forward remote ssh port like this:

```
ssh -N ec2-user@remote.server -R *:8005:localhost:8005 remote.server
```

Port 8005 is open on both remote and local systems.

Then start Express app locally:

```
var fs = require('fs')

var credentials = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt'),
    passphrase: 'ABCDEFGHJ123'
};

var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.end('it works');
})

app.listen(8005)
```

Now `curl` to the remote server:

```
$curl -k remote.server:8005
it works
```

Now add `https://`

```
$curl https://remote.server:8005
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed:
        The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
```

Why it works without `https://` and does not work with `https://`?

When it works without `https://`, is the connection secure?

Comment: you would probably need some debug information from the gnutls to get more information what is failing.

Comment: It's probably a problem with TLS setup, not with the tunnel. You can try debugging on the local machine first, by pointing domain to the local ip in /etc/hosts, and then debugging with the browser and `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443` command.

Comment: @AfanasiiKurakin this was needed to receive FB Messenger hooks, so your solution would not work.